# caldav client unknown to mdaemon

Tags: http, web, caldav

I am trying to install a graphic interface caldavzap (open source web client) on a server of the company (Windows Server 2003), so that it can show the calendar located in another domain.
https://www.inf-it.com/open-source/clients/caldavzap

The server where the resource or the calendar is the MDaemon mail server and I'm not the administrator.
The location of the web client does not seem complicated, but I always get an unauthorized 401 and cross domain error messages. Caldavzap tells me that there may also be problems with the TLS.
On the other hand, calendars can be viewed and created from mozila thunderbird (with plugin lighting). So I guess could see it from the customer caldavzap.
My question is:
Is it the customer's problem? Do I need to access the messaging server to allow access to my client that is on another server?

Answer (score 0):

If Caldavzap is a javascript client, the reason you're having a problem is because your external CalDAV service needs to emit CORS headers.

If you have no control over the service, there's no easy way around this. One way I can think of is to host a separate server yourself that does emit the right CORS headers and proxies HTTP requests to your actual CalDAV service.